# Using PHP value in javascript - working in alert() but not getelementbyid

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

i am using this:

```
$newPostID_fromCookie = $_COOKIE['scrollToBottom']+5000;
echo "
  <script>
  window.onload = function () {
    //document.getElementById('$newPostID_fromCookie').scrollIntoView();
    alert('$newPostID_fromCookie');
  }
  </script>
";
```

This correctly shows the value from the cookie in the alert, but i am getting 'is null' error when trying to use the value in the getElementById.

How can i use the value in this?

Comment: Does that element ID exist?  Specifically does it exist when this code runs?

Comment: So the element by the given ID is not in the DOM?

Comment: Judging by the `+`, `$newPostID_fromCookie` is a number. IDs should not be numbers.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol isn't basically anything allowed in html5?

Comment: @PeeHaa Yes, true, numeric IDs are acceptable in HTML5. However, older browsers won't like them, and it's just a bad idea anyway because it makes it much easier to end up with duplicate IDs ;)

Comment: try to add console.log(document.getElementById('cookie_$newPostID_fromCookie'));

Answer (score 0):

Your `$newPostID_fromCookie` seems to be an integer. [In xHTML, this is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) and maybe your browser does not like it. You should use a string (with a prefix for example):

```
document.getElementById('cookie_$newPostID_fromCookie').scrollIntoView();
```

Of course, change your HTML in consequence.

Answer (score -1):

The getElementById() does a DOM lookup and returns the first element with the specified id.
In this case $newPostID_fromCookie should be an id of an existing element in the DOM.